# Updating in database is not performed

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-update, prepared-statement

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("update schedule set date='"+date+"',stime='"+stime+"',etime='"+etime+"',hall='"+hall+"',loc='"+loc+"' where dept='"+dept+"' and code='"+code+"' ");
            st.setString(6,loc);
            st.setString(7,hall);
            st.setString(8,date);
            st.setString(9,stime);
            st.setString(10,etime);
            st.executeUpdate();
            fwd="success";
            return(fwd)
```

It doestn't return success. Is there any problem in the code?

Comment: That is not how *Prepared Statements* are supposed to be used.

Comment: the code runs successfully (without exception) ? last line changes to: `return fwd;`

Comment: I am pretty sure that will throw a `SQLException`, because 1) the statement doesn't contain parameters and 2) parameter index starts at 1, not 6.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all...

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("update schedule set date='"+date+"',stime='"+stime+"',etime='"+etime+"',hall='"+hall+"',loc='"+loc+"' where dept='"+dept+"' and code='"+code+"' ");

      int result=st.executeUpdate();
      if(result==1)            
             fwd="success";
       else
             fwd="fail";
       return(fwd);
```

Comment: That is **still** the wrong way to use a `PreparedStatement`. -1

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the placeholder(`?`). That's why you go in for a `PreparedStatment` on the first place, to avoid SQL injections.

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("update schedule set date = ? ..");
// st.setDate(paramIndex, value);
st.setDate(1, new Date()); // first index
```

Likewise, for every value you wanna set, you need to put a placeholder and set the value accordingly. Parameter index begins wtih `1` here.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this.**. you also make sure the query is correct. I'm assuming that query is valid.

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("update schedule set date=?,stime=?,etime=?,hall=?,loc=? where dept=? and code=? ");

            st.setString(1,date);
            st.setString(2,stime);
            st.setString(3,etime);
            st.setString(4,hall);
            st.setString(5,loc);
            st.setString(6,date);
            st.setString(7,code);

            st.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

schedule is the table right ? then you have to point it to the field you want to change like

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("update schedule set date='"+date+"',stime='"+stime+"',etime='"+etime+"',hall='"+hall+"',loc='"+loc+"' where dept='"+dept+"' and code='"+code+"' where scheduleId="+scId);
```